# How to install opencv 2.9 for python?

Tags: python, opencv

I have been having the exact same problem as described in [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/2061/how-to-set-resolution-of-video-capture-in-python/) post 
 and  someone in the answers suggested that you upgrade to opencv version 2.9. I was wondering how do that? I installed the version I have now by doing

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

Also, how can I check what version I'm running now? I'm on Ubuntu 13.10

EDIT:

After girardengo answer I know I'm on version 2.4.5 Thank you for that!

Comment: May I know how to type the "_version_" command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before installing the development version of OpenCV, I'd suggest to use this code to set the capture size (from the link you posted I assume you're using python):

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(device_no)
cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
```

To install the development version of opencv (3.0.0-dev today) please follow the steps below:

```
cd $HOME
mkdir opencv_src
cd opencv_src/
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
cd opencv/
mkdir release
cd release/
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: I've tried the commands you suggest and they don't work for my camera logitech c910. I'm compiling / installing the latest version now and will see if that makes a difference. thank you

Comment: Weird, I have a C920 and with opencv 2.4.5 (the default 13.10 version) it works fine. You can check one of mys script [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~checkbox-dev/checkbox/trunk/view/head:/providers/plainbox-provider-checkbox/bin/screenshot_validation)

Comment: it didn't work with the dev :( I'll mark this solved and post a new question about the error message I get.

Comment: hi evan54, just curious - are you using a mac?  also, did you install 2.9 or 3.0 based on the above instructions?  if you used opencv 3.0 in python did you still refer to it as cv2?

Comment: Sometimes you have to link the module `cd ~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ && 
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so cv2.so`

Answer (score 7):

Open terminal, then launch python interpeter:

```
python
```

then, import opencv:

```
import cv2
```

finally, print version:

```
cv2.__version__
```

if you want to install the latest development version of opencv, you can follow the instructions of the official documentation of opencv from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux%5finstall/linux%5finstall.html)

Answer (score 1):

Script is mentioned below, copy it and run it

```
sudo bash install_opencv.sh
```

Here is script...

```
# KEEP UBUNTU OR DEBIAN UP TO DATE

 sudo apt-get -y update
 sudo apt-get -y upgrade
 sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
 sudo apt-get -y autoremove

 #INSTALL THE DEPENDENCIES


 # Build tools:

 sudo apt-get install -y build-essential cmake


 # GUI:

 sudo apt-get install -y qt5-default libvtk6-dev


 # Media I/O:

 sudo apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev libjpeg-dev libwebp-dev libpng-
 dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libopenexr-dev libgdal-dev


 # Video I/O:

 sudo apt-get install -y libdc1394-22-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-
 dev libswscale-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libxvidcore-dev 
 libx264-dev yasm libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libv4l-
 dev libxine2-dev


 # Parallelism and linear algebra libraries:

 sudo apt-get install -y libtbb-dev libeigen3-dev


 # Python:

 sudo apt-get install -y python-dev python-tk python-numpy python3-
 dev python3-tk python3-numpy


 # Java:

 sudo apt-get install -y ant default-jdk


 # Documentation:

 sudo apt-get install -y doxygen



 # INSTALL THE LIBRARY (YOU CAN CHANGE '3.0.0' FOR THE LAST STABLE 
 VERSION)


 sudo apt-get install -y unzip wget
 wget https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/3.1.0.zip
 unzip 3.1.0.zip
 rm 3.1.0.zip
 mv opencv-3.1.0 OpenCV1
 cd OpenCV1
 mkdir build
 cd build
 cmake -DWITH_QT=ON -DWITH_OPENGL=ON -DFORCE_VTK=ON -DWITH_TBB=ON -
 DWITH_GDAL=ON -DWITH_XINE=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
 make -j4
 sudo make install
 sudo ldconfig

 # EXECUTE SOME OPENCV EXAMPLES AND COMPILE A DEMONSTRATION
 # To complete this step, please visit 
 'http://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian'.
```