# OpenCV error in setting resolution with c910

Tags: python, opencv

I've been trying to use OpenCV to control my webcam (Logitech c910) through python. I 've managed to capture images through .read() but they are 640 x 480 and I haven't managed to set the resolution to the max which is 2592 x 1944.

I used to have opencv 2.4.8 but now I have 3.0.0-dev

Here is the code I try and the outputs:

```
In [1]: import cv2
In [2]: cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L/V4L2: VIDIOC_S_CROP
In [3]: cap.open(1)
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L2: Pixel format of incoming image is unsupported by OpenCV
Out[3]: True
In [4]: r,f = cap.read()
VIDIOC_STREAMON: Bad file descriptor
In [5]: r
Out[5]: False
```

I installed 3.0.0-dev following the instructions from this other question I posted.
[How to install opencv 2.9 for python?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447409/how-to-install-opencv-2-9-for-python)

The reason I went with the dev version is because in this post someone said that resolved their problem.
http://answers.opencv.org/question/2061/how-to-set-resolution-of-video-capture-in-python/

Comment: Have you tried building OpenCV from source with `-D WITH_V4L=ON` and `-D WITH_LIBV4L=ON`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're building opencv from sources, try to follow the build process used by the [debian packaging](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=debian-science/packages/opencv.git;a=blob;f=debian/rules;h=0aa040217ad7fa0f28a0c42c42f040bed5a33c12;hb=HEAD) to ensure the compatibility with linux. I'm thinking about the V4L2 support for example:

```
CMAKE_ARCH_FLAGS += -DWITH_V4L=ON
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how do I use the link you provided? or the flag? Sorry for the ignorance

Comment: Having the same issue and I am curious on how to debug this as well.  I am a newbie with building on ubuntu so it would be appreciated.